# Laravel routes with multiple domain fail in link_to_action function

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have my `routes.php` as follows:

```
<?php
$approutes =function (){

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
        Route::get('profile/{user}','ProfileController@index');    
        Route::post('profile/{user}/update',array('as' => 'profile.update','uses' => 'ProfileController@update'));    
        Route::resource('posts','PostsController');    
        Route::resource('tags','TagsController');    
        Route::resource('health','HealthController');    
        Route::resource('health-categories','HealthCategoriesController');
    });

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
    ]);
};

$siteroutes =function (){
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'my.xxxx.com'],$approutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'my.xxxx.dev'],$approutes);

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.xxxx.com'],$siteroutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.xxxx.dev'],$siteroutes);
```

In my development `.dev` domains it is ok.

BUT when i tried to put it online in the .com domain all references from link_to_action (and possibly from every other route function) defaults to `.dev` domain.

I cant figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multi domain, use this code:

```
ln -s ~/Projects/directory  ~/.valet/Sites/domain_name
```

Example:

```
ln -s ~/Projects/laravel  ~/.valet/Sites/taylor
```

And change the route file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'laravel.app'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "Main Domain";
    });
});


Route::group(['domain' => 'taylor.app'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "Taylor Domain";
    });
});


//or 


Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.{tld}'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "Taylor Domain";
    });
});
```

In this project, the project name is **laravel**, the main domain is **laravel.app** and the taylor domain is **taylor.app**.

**Note:** I don't use the .dev domain. If you are using default valet settings, your domains are laravel.dev and taylor.dev.